# .htaccess needs to check for blank parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently, my .htaccess located at olddomain.com contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?  http://newdomain.com/?d=$1 [L]
```

So if one goes to:
**olddomain.com/docu443**
It's redirected to:
**newdomain.com/?d=docu443**

This is working fine except where there is a blank parameter:
**olddomain.com**
is redirected to:
**newdomain.com/?d=default.asp**

Instead, I need it to go to:
**newdomain.com**
with no parameters.

Yes, I'm a complete Apache noob so please spell out your answer please because otherwise I won't understand what you are talking about. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?  http://newdomain.com/?d=$1 [L]
```

Or check for the exception:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^default.asp$ http://newdomain.com/ [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?  http://newdomain.com/?d=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The first one didn't work. Same results. The second one works. I still don't understand it though. :)